# How to Schedule Tasks

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, scheduling, priority-queue, compareto

There is a carwash that can only service 1 customer at a time. The goal of the car wash is to have as many happy customers as possible by making them wait the least amount of time in the queue. If the customers can be serviced under 15 minutes they are joyful, under an hour they are happy, between 1 hour to 3 hours neutral and 3 hours to 8 hours angry. (The goal is to minimize angry people and maximize happy people). The only caveat to this problem is that each car takes a different amount of time to wash and service so we cannot always serve on first come first serve basis given the goal we have to maximize customer utility. So it may look like this:

> **Customer Line** :
>
> Customer1) Task:6 Minutes (1st arrival)
>
> Customer2) Task:3 Minutes (2nd arrival)
>
> Customer3) Task:9 Minutes (3rd)
>
> Customer4) Task:4 Minutes (4th)
>
> **Service Line**:
>
> Serve Customer 2, Serve Customer 1, Serve Customer 4, Serve Customer 3.

In this way, no one waited in line for more than 15 minutes before being served. I know I should use some form of priority queue to implement this but I honestly know how should I give priority to different customers. I cannot give priority to customers with the least amount of work needed since they may be the last customer to have arrived for example (others would be very angry) and I cannot just compare based on time since the first guy might have a task that takes the whole day.So how would I compare these customers to each other with the goal of maximizing happiness?

Cheers

Comment: Letting people with shorter jobs jump the queue will definitely make most people happy. The problem will be that depending on the overall queue load, some people might never get served. To make this a proper so question though, you'll need to provide code and state an actual problem with it.

Comment: Can the goal be expressed mathematically? E.g. are two happy and one angry customer better than three neutral customers?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to ordering calls to a call center. It becomes more interesting when you have gold and silver customers. Anyway:

Every car has `readyTime` (the earliest time it can be washed, so it's arrival time - which might be different for each car) and a `dueTime` (the moment the customer becomes angry, so 3 hours after readyTime).

Then use a constraint solver (like [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/)) to determine the order of the cars (*). The order of the cars (which is a genuine planning variable) implies the `startWashingTime` of each car (which is a shadow variable), because in your example, if  customer 1 is ordered after customer 2 and if we start at 08:00, we can deduce that customer 1's `startWashingTime` is 08:03.

Then the `endWashingTime` is `startWashingTime + washingDuration`.

Then it's just a matter of adding 2 constraints and let the solver `solve()` it:

- `endWashingTime` must be lower than `dueTime`, this is a hard constraint. This is to have no angry customers.
- `endWashingTime` must be lower than `startTime` plus 15 minutes, this is a soft constraint. This is to maximize happy customers.

(*) This problem is NP-complete or NP-hard because you can relax it to a knapsack problem. In practice this means: you can't write an algorithm for it that scales out and finds the optimal solution in reasonable time. But a constraint solver can get you close.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I prioritize them in my priority queue? I am thinking of creating a variable for each car that would be the time it takes to wash a car + the time the car arrived and sort these cars in my p queue based on this.